# What is the point of Object#presence in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In the Rails docs, [the example provided](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-presence) for the `Object#presence` method is:

```
region = params[:state].presence || params[:country].presence || 'US'
```

But isn't that just equivalent to:

```
region = params[:state] || params[:country] || 'US'
```

What is the point of using `presence`?

Answer (score 161, accepted):

Here's the point:

```
''.presence
# => nil
```

so if `params[:state] == ''`:

```
region = params[:state].presence || 'US'
# => 'US'
region = params[:state] || 'US'
# => ''
```

What's more, it works in similar way (that is, returns `nil` if object is 'empty') on every object that responds to `empty?` method, for example:

```
[].presence
# => nil
```

Here's the documentation, for reference:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-presence

Comment: @apneadiving no, after you require 'activesupport', every `Object` instance responds to `blank?`.
Reference:
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html

Comment: @apneadiving look at the `blank?` source. There's implemented this different behaviour that depends on if object responds to `empty?`.

Comment: `present?(): An object is present if it’s not blank?.`

Comment: Yes, and object is `blank?` if it responds to `empty?` and is empty or is `nil` or is `false`. That's what I meant.

Comment: sure, but you are slightly incorrect when you write `every object that responds to empty? method,` thats a side comment

Comment: @apneadiving 'in similar way' - that is, returns `nil` if object is empty.

Comment: ;) +1 t this answer with an example!

Comment: @apneadiving I edited my answer to make my point more clear. Feel free to edit it if you feel it isn't clear enough - after all, I'm not English native speaker.

Comment: I think more explaination about *what* is better. After I read your answer, I believe how presence work is "returns nil if object is 'empty"

Answer (score 24):

The real point of using `#presence` is that it **expands** the notion of *falsey values* to handle web and http scenarios. The docs don't make this purpose clear ... instead simply focussing on the method's API: The *what* but not the *why*. Web and HTTP is different from normal programming because a blank string is often what you get instead of a `nil` from a request.

In plain Ruby, however, an empty string is *truthy*. This makes web developers write a lot of redundant boilerplate code like the docs for `Object.presence` uses as its example, as others here have quoted.

The bottom line for people writing web applications in Rails is that we can (should) now use `#present?` and `#presence` with the standard Ruby short-circuiting or, `||`:

```
# Check for a param like this
@name = params[:name].presence || 'No name given'
```

That line properly handles everything the web server packs into the `request` params for us. While this plain old ruby does not:

```
# DON'T DO THIS
@name = params[:name] || 'No name given'
```

Answer (score 16):

`presence` is very useful when you want to return `nil` if object is not present and the object itself if the object is present. In other words you want a code that looks like this:

`object.present? ? object : nil`

Instead of the line above you can simply call `object.presence` and the method will do the work for you.

*Edit:* fixed question mark

Comment: the exact info I was looking for!

Answer (score 7):

As another example, `presence` lets me present my favorite [FizzBuzz](http://wiki.c2.com/?FizzBuzzTest) solution:

```
puts 1.upto(100).map { |n| "#{'Fizz' if n%3==0}#{'Buzz' if n%5==0}".presence || n }
```

Answer (score 4):

I just used it in a useful way I found neat. My variable is a string, if it's the empty string i want nil, otherwise I want it converted to an integer.

```
 x.presence.try(&:to_i)

 "".presence.try(&:to_i) # => nil
 "22".presence.try(&:to_i) # => 22
```

Comment: why `nil.to_i # => nil`? it should be zero

Comment: @NickolayKondratenko because sometimes you want to distinguish between a blank value and the string `"0"`.

Comment: @NickolayKondratenko Because `nil.to_i` is never being called, `x.presence` will return `nil` on empty string and `try(:to_i)` will only call `to_i` on the result _if it's not nil_. So what's really happening here is akin to `str.blank? ? nil : str.to_i`