# Multi-tenancy Rails Appartment generic elevator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multi-tenant

I use Apartment work in my Rails 4 application.

I followed this step :

1)

```
#config/initializer/apartement.rb
require 'apartment/elevators/generic'
```

2)

```
#config/initializer/application.rb
config.middleware.use 'Apartment::Elevators::Generic', Proc.new {|request|

  remember_token = request.cookies['remember_token']
  if remember_token.blank?
    nil
  else
    User.find_by(remember_token: remember_token).backoffice_company_id
  end
}
```

This works fine but it's not efficient because a request is done on the database on each request on the application.

How can I avoid this database access when the remember_token is unchanged from the last request (because it's the same user) ?

I tried to store this in a session variable but it's seems to be global à this level (application.rb) when 2 users use the application.

Thanks

Bruno

Comment: Just curious did you ever find a way to make this more efficient? I'm trying to do something like this and I can't even make it work the same way you did it. Thanks.

Comment: No, we didn't found a better solution to avoid these requests. We are still looking for any idea...

Answer (score 0):

Came across this setting something similar up today for specific subdomain routing on main domain, but domain-level routing on others.  Digging into the code that ships with apartment, they use `tenant.presence`, rather than ending with the return of the if/else.  Checking presence (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-presence) essentially gives an `||=` inline while checking.

See: [What is the point of object.presence?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19637499/what-is-the-point-of-object-presence/19637602)